# How to implement MS Access VBA access code that will remove invisible field data instead of just creating blocked empty white spaces?

Tags: vba, visibility, ms-access-2013, visible

I'm new to Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013 Access.

I am developing an application using:

-Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013 Access

I'm implementing an application that will generate various pdf files.

I have conditional business logic that determines if a particular field's data, and it's corresponding label should be displayed.  If said field's data does Not need to be displayed then the generated pdf will show empty blocked out spaces.

To elaborate, I have a lot of code that looks like the following:

```
 txtBoxInQuestion.Visible = Not IsNull(txtBoxInQuestion)
 lblInQuestion.Visible = Not IsNull(txtBoxInQuestion)
```

Therefore, if the conditional logic determines that a field and it's label should Not show up then I have all empty blocked out spaces showing up like in the following generated pdf

[image]

Could someone please tell me how I can implement the system in such a way that these empty blocked out spaces do Not show up?

Comment: You could make the texbox a subreport whose `Can Shrink` property is set to `Yes`.

Comment: The empty block space shown in the picture of the pdf contains lot of textboxes. Based on complex conditional logic, different textboxes will contain data, and other textboxes will be null.  Basically, it would be too cumbersome if I put each textbox in it's own subreport.  I would have too many subreports.  Is there any other way?

Comment: you could do something like `.height=abs(not IsNull(txtBoxInQuestion))*100` where 100 would be its shown height, same with width

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Which Report Event handler method should contain the .height=abs(not IsNull(txtBoxInQuestion))*100 code ? To elaborate, should I place it in Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer) , Private Sub Report_Current() or Private Sub Report_Load(), etc.,)

Comment: The TextBox itself has property CanShrink - seet it to true.